# asp.net Table height not changing

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a simple asp:Table control with static data.  The row heights for the table are to high so I want to set them to be narrower. I set the Height property, but the height of the table does not change.  The html is below:

```
<asp:Table ID="TextTable" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" CellPadding="10" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="234px">

<asp:TableHeaderRow HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="True" Height="15px">
<asp:TableHeaderCell>Folder Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
<asp:TableHeaderCell>Files Created</asp:TableHeaderCell>
   </asp:TableHeaderRow> 
<asp:TableRow runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="10px">
   <asp:TableCell runat="server">CJON</asp:TableCell>
   <asp:TableCell runat="server">8</asp:TableCell>
       </asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="10px">
   <asp:TableCell runat="server">Forum</asp:TableCell>
   <asp:TableCell runat="server">8</asp:TableCell>
       </asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="10px">
   <asp:TableCell runat="server">Connect</asp:TableCell>
   <asp:TableCell runat="server">4</asp:TableCell>
       </asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="10px">
   <asp:TableCell runat="server">Count</asp:TableCell>
   <asp:TableCell runat="server">1</asp:TableCell>
      </asp:TableRow>         
</asp:Table>
```

How do I set the Height of the rows and header row?

Comment: can you post the rendered HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set height and padding for `<th>` and `<td>` as well. Better if you do it in css. Here's how I would do it:

The markup:

```
<asp:TableHeaderRow HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="True" CssClass="myHeight15">
<asp:TableHeaderCell>Folder Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
<asp:TableHeaderCell>Files Created</asp:TableHeaderCell>
   </asp:TableHeaderRow> 
<asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="myHeight10">
   <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" runat="server">CJON</asp:TableCell>
   <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" runat="server">8</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
... ... ...
```

And my css in the head section:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .myHeight15 {
            height: 15px;
        }
        .myHeight15 th{
            height: 15px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .myHeight10 {
            height: 10px;
        }
        .myHeight10 td{
            height: 10px;
            padding:0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and added the above css code to my style sheet.  In design view, the table displays with the changes.  But when I run the project, the display in the browser shows the table in the original dimensions, with the heights of the rows as too wide. Why are the changes to the height not shown correctly in the browser?  I am using Firefox.

Comment: I got it to work!  I needed to remove the CellPadding attribute in the asp:Table element.